# How do I check if a constant is defined from a different class?

Tags: php, constants

How can I see if a constant is defined in an instantiated class?

I have:

```
Class foo {
  const BAR = 'baz';
}
```

and later `$foo` is getting passed into a function in another class wherein I check if it is set and use its value (or a default value):

```
Class abc {
  public function xyz($foo)
  {
    if (defined($foo::BAR)) {
      $var = $foo::BAR;
    } else {
      $var = 'default';
    }
  }
}
```

But no matter what I do, I can't get it to figure out if the constant is defined. It is either defined and works, or it is not defined and throws a `FatalError: Undefined class constant 'BAR'` before we can get to `else`.

These are the various dumps I've done (that I can recall) and their outcomes:

```
$foo::BAR            | string 'baz' (length=3)
$foo->BAR            | null
$foo::BAR !== null   | boolean true (when set) Error (when unset)  
defined($foo::BAR)   | boolean false
defined('$foo::BAR') | boolean false
defined("$foo::BAR") | boolean false
defined('BAR', $foo) | Error
```

If it helps at all, I'm working in Laravel 5.4 and PHP 5.6.

Comment: Class constant visibility is PHP 7.1+

Comment: I don't think that `"$foo::BAR"` really does what you think about. It tries to expand `$foo` as string and then do something else. Do not try that. I would even do not show that in this example just saying `false` since it's a programming mistake that can cause errors, and not just a `false` case for this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably works better with a class name instead of an object variable :

```
if(defined(get_class($foo).'::BAR')) // Do something
```